# How to avoid launching Fragment on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, android-datepicker

When an `EditText` line in the UI gains focus, a `DatePickerFragment` launches for the user to enter a date.  On orientation change, if the `EditText` line has focus and a previously entered date (length() > 0) and is launching a `DatePickerFragment` due to the below code.  I don't want the `DatePickerFragment` to launch though after an orientation change.  Is there a way to modify or add code so that if the `Activity` is newly created and the `EditText` line has focus it won't automatically launch the `DatePickerFragment` ?  Would it be a good idea to do something in `onResume()`?  Or do something with `!=null`?

```
ListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     ...
        if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0)) {
           DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
           newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
        else if (hasFocus) {
           ...
           DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
           newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `requestFocus()` on your `Edittext` remove it also go for something like this; move the below line outside the interface

```
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
```

and inside the interface go for a boolean attack

```
if(newFragment.isShow())// true if shown false if not
```

and your if statment checks out this way

*if & only if EditText has focus and the length is 0 show dialog, or if it has focus show dialog,there is no greater than 0 here*

Hope i helped

Comment: The blinking cursor is on the EditText line when the orientation change occurs, so the EditText line automatically hasFocus.  I don't have any requestFocus() on the the EditText.  Not sure what you mean by using the isShow I will have to research that...how does it help here?

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a new DatePickerFragment check to see if one already exists. If it doesn't exist then go ahead and add the DatePickerFragment. I'm assuming that "datePicker" is the tag that is used for the fragment transaction. You can check for the fragment by using

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("datePicker")==null) {
   //Add new DatePickerFragment
}
```

Let me know if that helps out.

Comment: Ok, I will try that out and be back to you shortly.

Comment: I used "else if (hasFocus && (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("datePicker")==null))" and the DatePickerFragment still launches after orientation change.  Just before the orientation change the cursor is blinking on the EditText line and the line has a previously entered date by the user.  After the orientation change, I just want to see the cursor blinking again on the EditText line and to see the previously entered date.  I don't want the DatePickerFragment to automatically launch.

Comment: I believe that moving the code to set the OnFocusChangeListener to onResume would prevent the onFocusChange call on orientation change.

Comment: Right but how do I get the DatePickerFragment to launch then if there is never an orientation change?  I still need the fragment to launch if the focus moves from somewhere else to the EditText line and the line has a previously entered date on it.  Any ideas?

Comment: To be clear, I was suggesting that you move the code block you posted to onResume in the Activity. So the DatePickerFragment should still launch when the EditText receives focus.